# How to compare tcl strings with don't care chars in the middle?

Tags: tcl, string-comparison

I have lists of strings I want to compare
When comparing 2 strings, I want to ignore a single char - making it a don't care.
e.g.
`Mister_T_had4_beers`
should be equal to:
`Mister_Q_had4_beers`
but shouldn't be equal to `Mister_T_had2_beers`
I know that `_had\d+` will always appear in the string, so it can be used as an anchor.

I believe I can split the 2 strings using regexp and compare, or use `string equal -length` to the point and from it onwards, but there must be a nicer way...

**Edit**
Based on the answer below (must read - pure gold!) the solution comes from regexp:
`regexp -line {(.*).(_had\d+.*)\n\1.\2$} $str1\n$str2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know which character can vary, the easiest way is to use `string match` with a `?` at the varying position.

```
if {[string match Mister_?_had4_beers $string1]} {
    puts "$string1 matches the pattern"
}
```

You can also use `string range` or `string replace` to get strings to compare:

```
# Compare substrings; prefixes can be done with [string equal -length] too
if {[string range $string1 0 6] eq [string range $string2 0 6]
        && [string range $string1 8 end] eq [string range $string2 8 end]} {
     puts "$string1 and $string2 are equal after ignoring the chars at index 7"
}
```

```
# Compare strings with variation point removed
if {[string replace $string1 7 7] eq [string replace $string2 7 7]} {
     puts "$string1 and $string2 are equal after ignoring the chars at index 7"
}
```

To have the varying point be at an **arbitrary position** is trickier. The easiest approach for that is to select a character that is present in *neither* string, say a newline, and use that to make a single string that we can run a more elaborate RE against:

```
regexp -line {^(.*).(.*)\n\1.\2$} $string1\n$string2
```

The advantage of using a newline is that `regexp`'s `-line` matching mode makes `.` *not* match a newline; we need to match it explicitly (which is great for our purposes).

If the strings you're comparing have newlines in, you'll need to pick something else (and the preferred RE gets more long-winded). There's lots of rare Unicode characters you could choose, but `\u0000` (NUL) is one of the best as it is exceptionally rare in non-binary data.

Comment: yes, it is an arbitrary position, and the regexp trick looks awesome! going to check it now :)

Comment: so, going back to my example, i'll use {(.*).(_had\d+.*)\n\1.\2$} ?